# Read a string with ncurses in C++

Tags: c++, string, ncurses

I'm writing a text-based game in C++. At some point, I ask the user to input user names corresponding to the different players playing.

I'm currently reading single char from ncurses like so:

```
move(y,x);
printw("Enter a char");
int char = getch();
```

However, I'm not sure how to a string. I'm looking for something like:

```
move(y,x);
printw("Enter a name: ");
std::string name = getstring();
```

I've seen many different guides for using ncurses all using a different set of functions that the other doesn't. As far as I can tell the lines between deprecated and non-deprecated functions is not very well defined.

Comment: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

```
std::string getstring()
{
    std::string input;

    // let the terminal do the line editing
    nocbreak();
    echo();

    // this reads from buffer after <ENTER>, not "raw" 
    // so any backspacing etc. has already been taken care of
    int ch = getch();

    while ( ch != '\n' )
    {
        input.push_back( ch );
        ch = getch();
    }

    // restore your cbreak / echo settings here

    return input;
}
```

I would discourage using the alternative `*scanw()` function family. You would be juggling a temporary `char []` buffer, the underlying `*scanf()` functionality with all its problems, plus the specification of `*scanw()` states it returns `ERR` or `OK` instead of the number of items scanned, further reducing its usefulness.

While `getstr()` (suggested by user indiv) looks better than `*scanw()` and does special handling of function keys, it would still require a temporary `char []`, and I try to avoid those in C++ code, if for nothing else but avoiding some arbitrary buffer size.

Comment: Your code works if we're not working with `UTF-8`. As I noticed, when we use `ch = getch();` and then `input.push_back(ch);` incomes actually not 1 char, but 2. And when we're deliting, they are deleting 1 by 1. I mean to delete 1 char on screen, we have to push `del` button twice. How can i fix it?

Comment: @AndrewKusachev: nwcurses is the wide-char extension to ncurses.

Comment: i'm compiling your code with `-lncursesw` flag, but still same mistake: 2 times push `del` to delete char

Comment: this is interesing, because `getstr();` also has this problem. I'm testing it on Russian language.

Comment: @AndrewKusachev: Can't really help you there; I dabbled in ncurses for a single, self-employed program only, and never touched the lib again since.